# JS - Cloning part of an external webpage

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to include a table from a webpage in a different domain. 
I went for the easiest path using a proxy to fulfill my request and embedded the page directly into an iFrame. 
Everything works fine but I'm still missing my initial (and final) objective: clone exactly (and only) one portion of the page, not the whole thing. 
This is the simple snippet:

```js
function loadIframe() {
  var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var _div = document.createElement('iframe');
  _div.src = "http://cors.io/?https://eshop-prices.com/?currency=EUR";
  _div.id = "iFrame";
  _div.width = "100%";
  _div.height = "1080";
  _body.appendChild(_div);
}


loadIframe();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  <title>eShop Prices</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="js/util.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Run this outside of stackoverflow or you'll see an empty iframe.

Comment: Naa, it works even as a snippet, no need to run it outside of SO

Comment: This won't wort on SO because cors.io is http and SO is https. If you check the console you'll see an error message confirming the request was blocked.

Comment: and what have I said in the last line of the post? xD

Comment: I know, I was replying to Federico klez Culloca.

Comment: ouh ok sorry :)

Comment: And what is the exact problem? When it's in same origin, you can do with an iframe code whatever you want. Use *iframe*.contentDocument.*

Comment: It works in firefox, but not in google chrome. Seems chrome is more secure.

Comment: I tested in FF 57 and I'm getting `contentDocument is null` error.